# Criar perfis em aplicação laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Preciso modificar minha aplicação laravel para que cada usuario veja seu conteudo particular, pois cada usuario tera informações próprias. Ja configurei a autenticação padrão usando make auth e esta funcionando bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo onde eu exibo os serviços do usuário.

```
class ServicoController extends Controller {

        private $usuario;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
            $this->middleware(function($request, $next){
                $this->usuario = auth()->user(); //Aqui você pega o usuario logado

                return $next($request);
            });

            public function index(){
                  $servico = Servico::where('user_id',$this->usuario->id)->get(); // Com isso você vai sempre buscar (como no meu caso) os serviços do usuário logado, ou seja, nessa rota cada usuário só vai conseguir ver seus serviços
            }

        }
```

Comment: Ok obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ajudou? Se sim, marque como a correta por favor!

Answer (score 2):

Agora você precisa criar uma middleware para restringir o acesso a página;
coloque o seguinte código dentro do construtor do seu controller.

```
    $this->middleware(function($request, $next) {

       if(auth()->user()->id == $sua_variavel_do_usuario_dono_do_perfil){
              retrun redirect('/outra-pagina'); // se o usuario não for o mesmo do perfil ele é redirecionado para outra página.
             }

       return $next($request);
       }
```

Comment: Dentro do controller de usuario? Vou precisar fazer binding nas rotas pra referenciar o id de cada usuario??

Comment: Ok, vou mexer aqui e testar, qq coisa te falo, obrigado.

Comment: Sim, ou você pode usar seu controller para pegar o usuário logado, passando para uma variável, com isso no seu método você busca no banco de dados as informações que você quer do determinado usuário e apresenta na tela em uma rota tipo "/perfil". Com isso somente o usuário dono das informações consegue ver, pois caso outro usuário tente acessar, ele vai buscas somente as suas informações!

Comment: Teria como vc me mostrar um exemplo mais detalhado, sem querer abusar, sou iniciante em laravel.